# How to access laravel collection in a foreach loop in blade template?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, foreach, collections

I want to get the user name details from the table `Users` with the author `id`s from the table `Pages`. For this, I have made a `foreach` loop and added the data to `users` array.

This gets the data but its not properly formatted to use in blade template. Below is the code :

```
$pages = \App\page::all();
    $users = array();
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        $user = \App\user::where('id', $page->author)->get('name');
        $users[] = $user;
    }       
    dd($users);
    return view('admin.pages', compact('pages', 'users'));
```

I have dumped the results with `dd($users)` method and got this:
[image]

I am using this code in the blade template to retrieve but getting blank white space at the `$users[$loop->index]->get('name')` place.

```
@foreach ($pages as $page)
            <tr>
              <th>{{ $page->id }}</th>
              <th>{{ $page->title }}</th>
              <th>{{ $users[$loop->index]->get('name') }}</th>
              @if($page->status = 'ACTIVE')
              <th><span class="label label-success">{{ $page->status }} </span></th>
              @elseif($page->status = 'DRAFT')
              <th><span class="label label-warning">{{ $page->status }} </span></th>
              @endif
              <th>{{ $page->Actions }}</th>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
```

Comment: Set assoc arrays whilst in the foreach loop

Comment: Can you explain me little more

Comment: Check answer, I've also included an explanation of how the answer code is different from your current code

Comment: You should not edit your question to indicate that it's solved. Marking an answer accepted will provide that information to future visitors.

Comment: Yeah but @ImmortalDude method was correct but not given me the expected result, So I did that. Your Answer is perfect so I marked your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've not defined your relationships properly. `App\User` should have this defined in the model:

```
public function pages()
{
    // have to specify the key name is author, not user_id
    return $this->hasMany("App\Page", "author");
}
```

And then in the `App\Page` model you have this:

```
public function pageauthor()
{
    // have to specify the key name is author, not user_id
    return $this->belongsTo("App\User", "author");
}
```

Then in your Blade template you just reference `$page->author->name`:

```
@foreach ($pages as $page)
            <tr>
              <th>{{ $page->id }}</th>
              <th>{{ $page->title }}</th>
              <th>{{ $page->pageauthor->name }}</th>
...
```

Comment: I will Try using relationships.

Comment: Relationships are the building blocks of Laravel, the app should be planned around them. I can tell by your database column names that this was not the case.

Comment: I am getting this error `Trying to get property of non-object (View: H:\laravel\work\resources\views\admin\pages.blade.php)`

Comment: I've told you how it should be done, but I can't help you debug your whole app. Do some dumping, do some reading. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: Yeah, I understand. Thanks @miken32

Comment: Just Tell me In which relationship my case comes. I have pages and author ids in the pages table where with these author Ids I can fetch their name from users table.

Comment: In your table `pages` you have a column called `author` that is a number, and in your table `users` you have a `id` column that is also a number? The `author` of the page is an `id` of a user? If `users` primary key is something other than `id` then code needs to be changed.

Comment: Yes, author of the page is an `id` of user.

Comment: There might be a conflict between the relationship name and the database column name. I'll make a small edit.

Comment: Glad to help. If you're just starting out on this, you will make your life a lot easier by reworking your database to fit with Laravel conventions. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions

Answer (score 1):

You can use foreach loop in controller to access its attributes.

like this

```
$users = \App\user::where('id', $page->author)->get('name');

$data = [];

foreach( $users as $user ){
        $data['name'] = $user['name'];       
   }
```

After that pass the $data array in your blade file and access name by $data['name'];

Comment: But We have to first loop users table with the author ids from pages table.

Comment: I have tried your code but it says $data vaiable is not defined in controller

Comment: did u pass $data in the blade ?

like this  : 

 return view('admin.pages', compact('pages', 'users', 'data'));

Comment: yeah, Passed But before that Getting error in the controller page first saying $data variable not defined.

Comment: I've edited the code section. please check. define $data= []; before the foreach

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should help you

Your controller

```
$pages = \App\page::all();
foreach ($pages as $page) {
    $user = \App\user::find($page->author)->pluck('name');
    if(isset($user)){
      $page['user_name'] = $user->name;
    } else {
       $page['user_name'] = 'N/A';
     }
}
return view('admin.pages', compact('pages'));
```

Your view

```
    @foreach ($pages as $page)
            <tr>
              <th>{{ $page->id }}</th>
              <th>{{ $page->title }}</th>
              <th>{{ $page->user_name) }}</th>
              @if($page->status = 'ACTIVE')
              <th><span class="label label-success">{{ $page->status }} 
    </span></th>
              @elseif($page->status = 'DRAFT')
              <th><span class="label label-warning">{{ $page->status }} 
</span></th>
               @endif
              <th>{{ $page->Actions }}</th>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
```

How is the code different from your current code

1) it writes the name of the user in the main collection itself ($pages) thereby allowing you to worry about looping through only one collection in your view

2) it's uses laravel's `find()` since a page can have only author (I assume) (Note : `find()` works based off of your primary key , in this case it will be searching through id column which is the most common primary key column)

3) it uses `pluck()`

Comment: Getting This error `Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance.` . name coloumn is there is the users table for sure.

Comment: Hmm then is seems that some of your users cannot be found

Comment: Every page have an author and evry author has name . Check users table --> `https://imgur.com/2OP5nYt` and pages table --> `https://imgur.com/v4YVzTY`

Comment: If you expect to be able to change `$pages` in your loop you need to be passing it by reference. Your loop does nothing right now.

Comment: It was solved by changing this `$user = \App\User::find($page->author)->pluck('name');` to `$user = \App\User::where('id', $page->author)->get('name');` and this `$page['user_name'] = $user->name;` to `$page['user_name'] = $user[0]->name;`

Comment: @miken32 the code I've suggested is based off of code I have personally used in daily developement, and I am certain it works, see the OP comment on the answer, it seems something is wrong with finding the value from users table

Comment: The only thing it does is add an element to `$page` which is an ephemeral variable that disappears with the next iteration. It affects nothing. What you want is `foreach ($pages as &$page)`

Comment: @Anonymous is the author field in page an integer??

Comment: No it was string. I forgot to make it an integer.Is it any problem If I use this way.

Comment: @Anonymous that is the reason why the suggested answer didn't work, IDs should really be integers

Comment: @miken32 no it doesn't disappear with the next iteration, the reason why the answer code didn't work is because the OP had set the author field as a string , find doesn't work with non integers as it searches the primary key column which is an integer

Comment: @miken32 thank you for your time, it is very much appreciated

Comment: very bad coding. Never use `find` inside a for loop. instead try to use `whereIn`, in this way you will query on database just 1 time not multiple times

Comment: @MamaD true, should be using relationship, but this is something the OP wanted, may be some restrictions on his end